# Is SonarQube 4.0 compatible with JDK 1.7?

Tags: jdk1.7, sonarqube-4.0

I am trying to look for the  documentation which would tell me the compatibility of SonarQube 4.0 with JDK 1.7 version, But i am unable to find it. I looked for it in sonar plugin version matrix and this link: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE43/Documentation. But hard luck. Could anyone please suggest me where to find it ? Expert advice would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit the following links:

1. [SonarQube Requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)
2. [SonarQube 4.4 Requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Requirements)
3. [SonarQube 4.5 Requirements](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Requirements)